# recoding dataframe in a fast way

Tags: r

I have the following data.frame sample from a big data.frame

```
df <- data.frame('V1'=c(0,0,0,2,2,2,1,1,1),'V2'= c(1,1,1,2,2,2,0,0,0))
```

My question is what can be applied efficiently to transform every `0` into `00`, every `1` into `01` and every `2` into `22` in the data.frame. I know I could use somethings like apply function or for loop but don't know what would be faster and more efficient.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `sprintf` to pad with 0 at the left, then change the '02' to '22' with either `sub` or `replace` etc.

```
df[] <-  lapply(df, function(x)  sub("^02", "22", sprintf(fmt = '%02d', x)))
```

---

Or with `strrep` and then `replace` the '11' with '01'

```
df[] <- lapply(df, strrep, 2)
replace(df, df ==11, '01')
```

Comment: thanks, could you explain me the difference of calling df[] and solely df ? thanks

Comment: @AlexandreMondaini  `lapply` returns a `list` of `vector`s.  We assing it to the orignal dataset while keeping the structure of the orignal dataset with `[]` instead of a `list`

Comment: Ah ah :D Bummer we can't upvote more than once. I upvoted your answer when you had only one suggestion, but feel like upvoting it again now that you added another way :D

Comment: Well, you are teaching me base R: I learnt R with the tidyverse. And often, when I answer (or try to answer) a question with dplyr, purrr, etc., you post a base R answer and it is always really instructive and shows me different methods and base R functions I don't know. Anyway, comments aren't for socializing, so my comments will likely get deleted :P But I am happy I got a chance to thank you :)

Comment: @prosoitos  SO is a great place to learn new things.  I learn new tricks from others, sometimes from newbies..  There is also a competitive element and the instant response from the OP/others makes it easier to rectify the mistakes in code and learn

Comment: Yup :) I got the SO bug lately :) and love the site

Comment: @prosoitos , answer the question in a tidyverse fashion for us then =)

Comment: Ah ah. OK. Give me a minute then

Comment: Very inelegant, but you could put either of @akrun's methods into a function and pass it to map instead of lapply: `func <- function(df) {df1 <- strrep(df, 2); replace(df1, df1 == 11, '01')}; map_df(df, func)`

Comment: @prosoitos  You can post it as an answer separately

Comment: Nan. I just stole your method and passed it to map. If I find some much more elegant way to do this in the tidyverse, I would. But this is just a variation of your solution.

Comment: @akrun I have a problem. in df[] <-  lapply(df, function(x)  sub("^02", "22", sprintf(fmt = '%02d', x))) it converts all integer values into characters , when converting back to numeric or integer the format 00 drops to 0 and and 01 drops to 1. how can I conserve the double digit property of numbers that begin with 0 . is it possible ??? I know mathematically is the same but this is a needed encoding.

Comment: @AlexandreMondaini  `00` is not integer.  It is `character`

Comment: @akrun yes exactly when transforming to integer `00` loses one zero and turns out to be 0. same happens with `01` to 1

Comment: @AlexandreMondaini  Yes, that is how the numeric/integer type works in `R`.  If you need to have a class with different print methods, have to create a new print method for that